# I received a tensorflow error when doing (import tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 58, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 28, in <module>
>     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 24, in swig_import_helper
>     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
> "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py",
> line 243, in load_module
>     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py",
> line 343, in load_dynamic
>     return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\roblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

Comment: Hi @Alexb_06. Welcome to the community. It looks like your environment is not set up correctly. It is hard to say why exactly, try adding a small code example you were working on. It would help if you say if you've done the pre-requisite steps to install the tools and libs. The error message seem to indicate there is a problem with the tensorflow runtime :`Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.`

Comment: import numpy as np
from grabscreen import grab_screen
import cv2
import time
from directkeys import PressKey,ReleaseKey, W, A, S, D
from alexnet import alexnet
from getkeys import key_check

import random

WIDTH = 160
HEIGHT = 120
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 10
MODEL_NAME = 'pygta5-car-fast-{}-{}-{}-epochs-300K-data.model'.format(LR, 'alexnetv2',EPOCHS)

t_time = 0.09

Comment: I have no idea why I just can't install TensorFlow normally it always comes up with an error

Comment: Try following one of the official tutorials that they have, it looks like there is a problem with the environment.

Comment: Do you need visual studio 2019, because I only have 2010, 2015 and 2017

Comment: I got visual studio 2019 it did nothing

Comment: I installed python 3.7.0 and I got a different error and i also Enabled NTFS long paths since the the error i got is related to it in some way

Comment: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: unless I have to high of a version of python or TensorFlow is 32bit when i have 64bit python and i also have 64bit